# Reading memory from a process (game in this case)

Tags: c#, memory-management

I'm making a autoclicker atm to get back into C# before my school starts again. I've been playing with php as an intern the last 5 months, when we get back to school php will be gone and C# will come looking around the corner.

I have played with C# for a long time, just some fun things whenever I get an idea, nothing special. Now I was making a autoclicker with record function so I could automate some things in a game, but I wanna take it a step further, memory reading!

Untill right now I found it so hard to find some decent info on it (dont know exactly where to look for) that im stuck. I want to make something that you can compare to an aimbot, but nothing commercial or anything, just want to experiment. I want to know the location of lets say ghosts from pacman, or the bal in pinball, or even airplanes in a flying game.

How do I start with this? I've read some things about how memory works and some functions to actually get it. But I dont know how to FIND the addresses. Also I dont know how to use them in a if statement for example.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: You mean reading a pointer from a game?

Comment: Exacly, the x/y/z value, maybe more info, who knows! I just dont know where to start.

Comment: Are you asking about accessing memory in your own process, i.e., your own executing code, or in any arbitrary running process?

Comment: Another, a running game for instance.

Comment: What game are you making the trainer for? Usually people code game trainers in C++ (like me).
There are several different tools that you can use to find addresses like ollydbg and CheatEngine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check [(C#)ReadProcessMemory](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/8ed8bb56-07d9-4df8-bdb1-357e88cffb01) out.

Answer (score 1):

[Cheat Engine](http://cheatengine.org/index.php) can help you find the memory adresses you need, although it is a rather tedious task. It also lets you change stuff if you want to experiment. 
There are also [Tutorials on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLtyLvhvS-Q) and on the [CheatEngine forum](http://forum.cheatengine.org/viewtopic.php?t=537193&sid=17644f9776a5c1e276deb3d1d869426d)

Comment: Ye, but with the more advanced games I've been unable to find the addresses. Think ill go find some more advanced tutorials then.

Comment: @Gideon if you cant find them with cheat engine, you prolly won't find them with C# too

Comment: I can imagine, but the point is that I want to learn how to do it, I'm not asking for a solution or a working piece of code. If I practise with CE, will it be easier in the long run with programming?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for writing trainers is to go native directly. Learn some C and C++ then use ReadProcessMemory. Working with native pointers in C# even in unsafe mode is terribly hard and ugly. Working with P/Invoke is not that terrible but for your case the only cool thing C# is giving to you is WinForms. Managed C++ is the best option if you need WinForms and native pointers in other processes in the same place :)